# Repeat an asynchronous request if it fails?

Tags: ios, swift, http, asynchronous, http-status-code-404

I am writing an ios app that relies on being able to tell when a user is connected to wifi and, when he or she connects or disconnects, send an asynchronous request using alamo fire.

The first time I connect, my asynchronous succeeds.

However, after I first connect, any toggling of the wifi results in 404s.

I suspect this is because I am sending the request as soon as the user connects/disconnects, meaning that for a brief moment he or she has no internet service.

My question is, can I repeat the request if it fails or is it possible to "cache" the requests I want to make and wait until the user has internet connection to make them?

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to solve this. One is to call the download method recursively again and so implementing an automatic retry mechanism on errors:

```
func downloadSomething() {
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
             .response { request, response, data, error in
                 if let error = error {
                    log(error)
                    self.downloadSomething() // recursive call to downloadSomething
                 } else {
                     // do something on success
                 }
              }
}
```

You can extend this by:

- showing the user also an altert view asking him if he want's to retry
  the download or not before retrying the download. (depending on your
  UI strategy on network errors)
- a specified count of automatic re-trys and *then* ask the user.
- checking the error status code and then depending on the code do
  different network error handling strategies...
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no needed to re-invented apple code like [reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) or this **swift** [reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) porting. You can able to check if a user is connected to the net or wifi very easily:

```
class func hasConnectivity() -> Bool {
    let reachability: Reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
    let networkStatus: Int = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().rawValue
    return networkStatus != 0
}
```

For a Wi-Fi connection:

```
(reachability.currentReachabilityStatus().value == ReachableViaWiFi.value)
```